# Microsoft 365 hotkey to switch between styles

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I would like to please find a hotkey/shortcut that will switch between styles in Word (I'm using 365 but have wanted to do this for several versions).  So to clarify, under the home tab, there are the styles "Normal, No Spacing, Header 1, Header 2," etc.  I would like to press a keyboard shortcut so I can tab between all and any of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What are the hotkeys for applying heading styles?

- Apply the Normal style.   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- Add or remove one line space before a paragraph.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero)
- Apply the Heading 1 style.    <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+1</kbd>
- Apply the Heading 2 style.    <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+2</kbd>
- Apply the Heading 3 style.    <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+3</kbd>
- Single-space lines.   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Source [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938)

---

**"If you happen to know a shortcut for the No Spacing style, that would be even better"**

"No Spacing" changes line spacing to single and spacing before and after paragraphs to 0 pts.

The following almost does it:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero)

  I don't know of a shortcut to remove the spacing *after* a paragraph, but you could apply <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to the *following* paragraph.

You could also make **No spacing** your **default** paragraph style, see [How to make "No Spacing" between lines as default?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010se-word/how-to-make-no-spacing-between-lines-as-default/9f1998cd-d0e1-4cf6-9b7a-5bff69f4c396).

Comment: Great, thanks very much.  If you happen to know a shortcut for the No Spacing style, that would be even better.  That was what I was originally looking for, but I couldn't find it anywhere on Google or Word Support.

Comment: "No spacing" isn't that what `CTRL+0` (zero) following by `ctrl+1` does?

Comment: @Mark answer updated.

Comment: It's close, but doesn't get me into the box in the styles area called "No Spacing."  Ctl-shift-alt-s, and then F6 gets into the style box, but is kinda cumbersome, lol.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box shortcut to go to "No Spacing."  Only the ones that [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) wrote in [this](https://superuser.com/a/882636/337631) answer exist.  You can always custom make a hotkey.